# Javascript code logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, logical-operators

```
$(".combinations .combination").each(function () {
    if ($(this).data("id")) {
        var i = {};
        $(this).find(".metric").each(function () {
        i[$(this).data("name")] = $(this).data("value")
    });
    var n = !0;
    $.each(i, function (e) {
         t.hasOwnProperty(e) && t[e] == i[e] || (n = !1)
    }), (n || 0 == i.length) && (e.id = $(this).data("id"), e.url = $(this).data("url"), e.link = $(this).data("link"), e.name = $(this).data("name"), e.image = $(this).data("image"))}
    }),
```

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to learn by reading the interesting code.

Please help me understand the code above; what does n = !0 mean?

What is this and how it works?

```
t.hasOwnProperty(e) && t[e] == i[e] || (n = !1)
(n || 0 == i.length) && (e.id = $(this).data("id")
```

and what do the commas between them mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is minified code that's had white-space re-added.  It's not meant to be read by humans, it's meant to be as short as possible.  Because of that, there are odd things like:

```
!0 === true // 0 evals to false, "not false" = true
```

commas are simply a way of adding a new instruction.  They're very similar (though not identical) to semi-colons in JavaScript.  e.g. you can write `x=5, y=10`

The `hasOwnProperty` bit is effectively:

```
if( !( t.hasOwnProperty( e ) && t[e] == i[e] ){
    n = false;
}
```